# Did the Early Church practice the salutation of “Peace to this House”, as had been taught by Jesus in Luke 10:5?

Tags: church-history, early-church, tradition, gospel-of-luke, peace

We Jesus instructing his disciples in Lk 10:1-5:

> After this the Lord appointed seventy-two others and sent them two by two ahead of him to every town and place where he was about to go.  He told them, ....... “When you enter a house, first say, ‘Peace to this house "

Though the "Shalom" instruction was given only to the 72 disciples, all members of the community are likely to have adopted the practice. The practice over a long period of time, may have been replaced by other forms of Christian salutations like Praise the Lord, and even by secular salutations like Good Morning.

My question therefore is: Did the members of Early Church practice the salutation of "Peace to this House", as had been taught by Jesus in Luke 10:5? Inputs from any denomination are welcome.